# iOS Direction Glow

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create a "mini-map."  It's a circle filled with markers, and I want the border of the circle to glow in places to indicate to the user to indicate that more markers are beyond the minimap in a given direction.

I can give the circle a 'glowing' blue border by drawing, below it, a blue circle with a slightly larger radius.  I think that I can make this blue border brighter in some places than others by giving its CALayer a mask.  (I've tried giving it a gradient mask, and it works.)

Assuming that I can make the proper calculations to determine how bright a given pixel should be (given the position of markers beyond the minimap's viewport), how do I set the individual pixels of a CALayer?  Or is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm looking for besides making a complicated alpha value calculation for each pixel in the circle?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard (for me, anyway) to visualise the effect you're after. Can you add a screenshot, or a link to a screenshot?

Comment: I Tried my circle sector answer (now deleted) but it was a bit rubbish. Adding cashapelayer circles with shadows to the outside of the main map circle would be next guess. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I managed to draw an arc using UIBezierPath, but the challenge will be making the arc brightest (highest alpha) in the middle and fading (lowest alpha) near the ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.   I drew a series of 1-pixel arcs, each with a different stroke color.

```
void AddGlowArc(CGContextRef context, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat radius, CGFloat peakAngle, CGFloat sideAngle, CGColorRef colorRef){
    CGFloat increment = .05;
    for (CGFloat angle = peakAngle - sideAngle; angle < peakAngle + sideAngle; angle+=increment){
        CGFloat alpha = (sideAngle - fabs(angle - peakAngle)) / sideAngle;
        CGColorRef newColor = CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha(colorRef, alpha);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, newColor);
        CGContextAddArc(context, x, y, radius, angle, angle + increment, 0);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

And then, in DrawRect,

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
AddGlowArc(context, 160, 160, 160, angle, .2, [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.76 blue:.87 alpha:1].CGColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my [much longer] solution which would allow each glow-point layer to be added and animated individually if needed. The small circle is added on the circumference of a larger one and that larger circle is rotated. Enjoyed getting my head around this even though you answered the question

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGPoint circleCenter = CGPointMake(300.f, 300.f);
    CALayer *outerCircle = [self outerCircleToRotateWithCenter:circleCenter andRadius:100.f];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:outerCircle];

    CGFloat rotationAngleInDeg = 270.f;
    CGFloat rotationAngle = (M_PI * -rotationAngleInDeg)/180.f;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngle, 0.f, 0.f, -1.f);
    [outerCircle setTransform:transform];
}
```

Using method:

```
- (CALayer *)outerCircleToRotateWithCenter:(CGPoint)circleCenter andRadius:(CGFloat )radius {
    // outer circle
    CAShapeLayer *container = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *containerCircle = [UIBezierPath
                            bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, radius, radius)];
    [container setPath:containerCircle.CGPath];
    [container setBounds:CGPathGetBoundingBox(containerCircle.CGPath)];
    [container setPosition:circleCenter];
    [container setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
    [container setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor]; // REMOVE
    [container setFillColor:nil];

    // smaller circle
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [container addSublayer:circle];
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath
                            bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 25.f, 25.f)];
    [circle setPath:circlePath.CGPath];
    [circle setBounds:CGPathGetBoundingBox(circlePath.CGPath)];
    [circle setFillColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
    [circle setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
    [circle setPosition:CGPointMake(radius/2.f, 0.f)];
    [circle setOpacity:0.4f];

    // shadow
    [circle setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
    [circle setShadowRadius:4.f];
    [circle setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.f, 0.f)];
    [circle setShadowColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
    [circle setShadowPath:circlePath.CGPath];

    return container;
}
```

I'm guessing the smaller circle could be added and rotated in a single transform rather then being a sublayer.